# Bad sectors on a hdd, how to know if and which data has been lost?

Tags: hard-drive, bad-sectors

My HDD is failing, the backup is made, only had 1 important file of 200 GB, I have currently 399 uncorrectable sector count and 399 pending sector count, plus 4874 reallocated sectors count. My hdd is 1000 GB.

I would like to know if I have lost something in my 200 GB file, including very small txt file of a few bytes.

Is there a way to know ? If not, how to calculate the odds of data lost in this file with the smart data ?

Thank you.

Comment: You would have to compare it to the original file in order to tell if the file was fragmented on any of those bad sectors.

Comment: The problem is I don't have the original file size.

Comment: If you don't have an copy of the file, you know isn't corrupt, to compare the file then there is no way to know the copy you have is corrupt or not.

Comment: If something is corrupt, even a very small text file, can the file disappear completely or does it always remain in its place, but the size become 0 byte or impossible to open ?

Comment: Depends what fragment of the file is corrupt.

Comment: I see. So theorically if I'm really unlucky some small text files could be completely invisible instead of being there but corrupted ?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1218312/pending-sector-issue-does-this-mean-the-hdd-is-failing/1218317#1218317

Comment: If the corruption affected the file's data area, its actual content, then it will appear in the file tree at its original place. It might still be readable, but with more or less noticeable errors. It's easy to notice with JPG images: the color layers are screwed up beyond the corruption. On audio/video files you may hear/see a glitch. On text files you may see an empty or scrambled portion. But if a corruption affects the area in the MFT containing the location and metadata for a file, then that file will no longer appear. (Can still be recovered by a raw file carving tool like Photorec.)

Answer (score 1):

How did you back up your drive?

As Ramhoud explained if you don't have your original file and the data on that 200GB file is readable and executable there's no way of knowing if anything got corrupted or not. Usually, corrupted data can't be opened and would produce an error.

Is the old drive still in operation? Can you read the original data from it? Maybe you can see which sectors is the data taking and compare them with the problematic sectors on the drive and see if there's a possibility of some of the data being there.

Comment: I copy pasted my important files. I have my original file that might have lost data. The old drive is still powered on, I have access to the file.

Comment: In this case can you compare the two and see if anything is missing? 
Also check what paradoxon wrote!

Answer (score 0):

First of S.M.A.R.T data is a bit of a mixed bag. It tends to be not outstandingly accurate / reliable. It is just reporting what the disk says. It is not asking any questions. It is useful as a warning sign.

Bad blocks doesn't always equal to lost data. Disks don't just write data and pray that never ever something goes wrong. The data is  protected by forward error correcting codes and in many cases can be recovered from a bad block and moved. You can first try boot a linux distro and and us bad blocks command or use the tool packaged with windows for drive analysis and repair. Th badblocks command would be:

> badblocks -vs /dev/sd#

Where # is the drive number. I would recommend booting a linux and us bad blocks since it is usually better to do this while the drive is not in use.

These tools are fine for a first try. If they fail there are more sophisticated solutions. My trusted one for years has been SpinRite. It is not open or free but it is very affordable and has been around for years. I would not use it to "resurrect" disks for prolonged us as people tend to do, but it is very useful for data recovery and the price is right. If your data is precious to you it might be worth spending the 90 bucks go give it a try.

> [GRC SpineRite](https://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm)

And for the future ( I am sorry but I have to stress this ), do make regular backups. It is not paranoid to do so. When done properly it is very cost effective counter measure to many problems. Disk failure, theft, fire, human error and even many types of virus infections. Take a regular full system backup (once you made major system changes or quarterly, you only need the most recent one) and make daily (if you are brave weekly) backups. If stuff hits the fan you can be back to normal within 30 min.